# Unity, C# - can't increase gravity in endless runner?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to Unity and am building an endless runner in Unity 3d off this tutorial: http://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/runner/

I have followed the tutorial verbatim and have tried several approaches but can't increase the gravity in game - right now I have the block moving and jumping, but no matter what vectors I apply in the jump or any other variable I change the block does not "jump up" and come back down "quickly" or like most endless runners.

The gravity is too little - my cube floats in the air a while before coming down.

I am trying to achieve a gravity affect like in Jetpack Joyride; a normal strength of gravity. Gravity is checked on my Runner object and It seems as though Unity's gravity is "fixed" at a low strength.
I have tried going to Input Settings and increasing gravity from 1000 up, I have tried altering Vector of jump.

I have increased mass of the Runner object. Nothing affects gravity.

How can I increase gravity in Unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the global gravity in a unity game, you can access it through Physics.gravity. You can either set it to a new vector3 or you can multiply it by a factor. 
Examples:
Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 10, 0)
or 
Physics.gravity *= 3;

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the menu Edit> Project Settings> Physics, you can alter the global gravity of your project.

However, falling slowly **USUALLY** means that the scale of your models are wrong. for example, typically 1 unit in unity is 1 m. But if your model is 100x100 units, then that means it's 100m tall. Say it jumps 3x the height of itself, then it has to fall 300m. a fall from 300m would take a hell of a long time at earth's gravity compared to something like 2m.

So: 1) make sure your gravity is set to something reasonable, and 2) make sure things are in the correct scale. A humanoid character should be somewhere in the range of 2 units (2m ~= 6 feet).